# get Perl hash keys part of a string/regex without a loop?

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I'm not even sure how to phrase the question in a single line, here is what I need:

I need to get an element of a hash key that is "subset" of a given string. So if my hash is

```
%h = ( 'ab' => 1, 'cd' => 2);
```

and the string is `abc123`, I would get `ab` from the hash.

I know I could do

```
$str = 'abc123';
foreach (keys %h) {
    print "$_ \n" if $str =~ m/^$_/;
}
```

But I'm asking if there's a more efficient way, like the way it would work if I was matching the other way around like so

```
%h = ('abc123' => 1, 'def456' => 2);
print "$_ \n" for grep /^ab/, keys %h
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're after. Your second example is the same "way round" as the first, because you're selecting a subset of the hash keys. The only difference is that it looks more concise because you've hidden the loop in a `grep` call

Comment: please see my edit for the second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can hide the loop inside a call to `grep`, as in your second example

```
my %h = ( ab => 1, cd => 2 );
my $str = 'abc123';

print "$_\n" for grep { $str =~ /^$_/ } keys %h;
```

but there is likely to be little or no speed advantage

If you wanted to find only *one* of the hash keys then you could build a regex from them, like this

```
my $re = join '|', sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %h;
$re = qr/$re/;
```

and then find the first matching hash key like this

```
print "$1\n" if $str =~ /^($re)/;
```

Comment: the second part is good, thanks! Yes, I'm only looking for a single match.

Comment: however, can I ask why the sort?

Comment: @mavili: The sort is so that matches of longer keys are found first, so `abc` would be caught before `ab`

Comment: actually, the for loop is at least twice quicker than the joining of keys and matching the regex! I'm surprised but timing it with only a couple of keys gives me 5.698e-05ms and 2.193e-05ms for your answer and the for loop, respectively. I wonder if the benefit would be if there was a huge number of keys?

Comment: @mavili: You should test only the regex match statement. The construction and compilation of the pattern on the preceding two lines need be done only once. And yes, you are likely to get bigger advantages with larger hashes because the regex engine constructs a trie to perform the comparison

Comment: yup, right I can already see the advantage with only around 20 elements.

Comment: @mavili: Good. I hope you've noticed that I added an additional compilation phase with the statement `$re = qr/$re/`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no, not really. You can't find the substring that matches without checking each substring. A `for` or a `map` isn't gaining you *efficiency* they're looping implicitly behind the scenes anyway.

However you *might* gain some efficiency by compiling your regular expressions in advance - see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators - given they're static.

Answer (score -1):

```
map {print "$_ \n" if $str =~ m/^$_/;} keys(%h);
```

Comment: I don't think map will be any faster than for or foreach. In fact, a quick Google search shows that it might even be slower!

Comment: It is also a misuse of `map` because you are ignoring the return value. `map` is meant to translate one list to another by applying a function to each element

Comment: There is no difference between map and foreach. There internal implementation is the same. map is perl's anther way of doing the same thing.

Comment: It's just a demo code snippet. It may return list of matched item.